# PostGIS Cube limit by distance

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am running some tests with this query:

```
SELECT
    recipe_id,
    macros,
    cube_distance (macros,
        CUBE (ARRAY [68, 78, 39])) AS distance
FROM
    indexable_recipes
ORDER BY
    distance
LIMIT 50;
```

Which works fine, in order to get the 50 best matches. However, **what I really need, is to select ALL records, which has a distance of a maximum of X - for example 10**.

Also, I need to select the matches by DISTINCT(recipe_id)

How are you doing that? I have found various distance functions, like ST_Distance, but can't seem to get any of them working with a Cube object, as it isn't using Point's which these functions require, as far as I can see.

I am running PostgreSQL v10.

Comment: Hey there. Could you provide some sample data? Also, if possible add the expected results :) cheers

Comment: PostGIS and Cube are different things.  Which one are you actually using?

Comment: I am using https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/cube.html

Comment: Currently having:

SELECT
 DISTINCT ON (IR.recipe_id) R.id, distance, R.name
FROM (
 SELECT
  recipe_id,
  cube_distance (IR.macros,
   CUBE (ARRAY [40, 40, 20])) AS distance
 FROM
  indexable_recipes_test AS IR) as IR
  INNER JOIN recipes AS R ON IR.recipe_id = R.id
 WHERE
  distance < 10

which executes in 200ms for 400k results, finding all distinct matches with a max distance of 10, and joining the recipes to get the recipe details. Not sure if this is the quickest method.